# Bundle and export typescript sources

Tags: typescript

I want to bundle my typescript sources in to a .js file, so it can be used in other javascript projects.
For example

```
├── index.ts
├── sum.ts
└── minus.ts
```

bundle to

```
 ├── index.ts
 ├── sum.ts
 ├── minus.ts
+└── build/
+     └── math.js
```

so in html

```
<script src="math.js" > </script>
<script > 
    a = math.sum(6, 7);
</script>
```

And all imported node modules must be also bundled.

Answer (score 0):

`tsc` with the `outFile` option will bundle the JavaScript generated from your TypeScript files.  But if you want to bundle imported node modules, you'll need to use a [module bundler](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+module+bundler) such as Webpack, Rollup, or Browserify.  Some module bundlers, including Webpack, have plugins available that allow them to accept TypeScript files as input without requiring a separate `tsc` step.